# $\dim U + \dim U^\perp = \dim V$. Example for being wrong when not nondegenerate

Tags: linear-algebra

$\beta\colon V \times V \to K$ is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form and $U$ is a linear subspace of $V$. Then this equation is proven: $\dim U + \dim U^\perp = \dim V$.

I need to find an example of

(1) it being wrong, when $\beta$ is not nondegenerate and

(2) why not in every case $V = U \oplus U^\perp$

I already made the proof of the equation being right, but I do not know any examples in which this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case when $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\beta(v,w)=\langle v, A w\rangle$ (the standard dot product) where $A$ is the $2 \times 2$ matrix given by
$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Now, take $U = V$. Then 
$$
U^{\perp} = \operatorname{span}\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c}0 \\1 \end{array} \right) \right\}
$$
and you get $\operatorname{dim}(U)+\operatorname{dim}(U^{\perp}) = 3 > \operatorname{dim}(V)$. Moreover, since in this case $U \cap U^{\perp} \neq \varnothing$, it is no longer true that $V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier (one might say, trivial) example is given by $\beta$ being identically zero, with a non-zero vector space $V$. Then $V = V^\perp$ and the sum of their dimensions exceeds the dimension of $V$.

As for your second question, take $V= \mathbb R^2$ and $\beta ((x,y), (w,z)) := xw-yz$. Notice the vector $(1,1)$ is perpendicular on itself. Take $U :=$ its span.